Running timed process in background (MATLAB)
I am trying to run a psychophysics experiment in MATLAB, where timings of stimuli are very crucial. I have code to generate a sequence of ones, twos, and threes, each of which will trigger different stimuli to be displayed. When stimulus 2 is displayed, the participant has 1s to respond via a button press (using a ResponsePixx button box).
I need each stimulus to be delivered 0.5s after the previous, which means that the response time to stimulus 2 overlaps with the delivery of the following stimulus. So I think I need to somehow track for the button press in the background whilst continuing to deliver the stimuli sequence.
Here's the simplified version that just reduces it down to this current problem:
% Create sequence of numbers
sequence = %FUNCTION OUTPUTS 1XN SEQUENCE OF ONES, TWOS, AND THREES

for iSequence = 1:length(sequence)
   
    disp(sequence(iSequence)) % Stand-in for displaying proper stimuli
    
    if sequence(iSequence) == 2
        % wait for 1 second whilst continuing display of sequence)
        % During this time, other code will run to track for participant responses
        disp("Time elapsed") 
    end
    
    pause (0.5)
    
end


I have done some testing with parfeval with no success - the output is displayed correctly, but interrupts the timing of the main sequence delivery (I assume as a delay to fetching the outputs from the parallel pool, but to be honest I have very little experience with parallel processing so I'm not sure):
delete(gcp('nocreate'))
clear 

background = parpool(1);

sequence = % createTrialSequence



for iSequence = 1:length(sequence)
    disp(sequence(iSequence))
    
    if iSequence > 1
        if sequence(iSequence - 1) == 2
            fetchOutputs(evalButton)
        end
    end
    
    if sequence(iSequence) == 2
        evalButton = parfeval(background, @trackInBackground, 1);
    end
    
    pause(0.5)
    
end

I have also tried using an event and listener, but this also pauses the delivery of the sequence (again, not hugely familiar with how these work, so may be missing something crucial):
clear
event = targetAppeared;
listener = trackTargetAppearance(event);

sequence = %createTrialSequence



for iSequence = 1:length(sequence)
    disp(sequence(iSequence))
    
    
    if sequence(iSequence) == 2
        event.isTarget
    end
    
    pause(0.5)
    
end


classdef targetAppeared < handle
    events
        targetEvent
    end
    methods
        function isTarget(obj)
            notify(obj, 'targetEvent')
            
        end
    end
end

classdef trackTargetAppearance < handle

    methods
        function obj = trackTargetAppearance(targetObj)
            addlistener(targetObj, 'targetEvent', @trackTargetAppearance.handleEvent)
        end
    end
    
    methods (Static)
        function handleEvent(~, ~)
            startTime = GetSecs; %get system time, from PsychToolBox
            while GetSecs < (startTime + 1)
                continue
            end
            disp("Target Response Window elapsed")
        end
    end    
end


This is a potential solution using a timer
Excuse the clutter of code due to building a minimal GUI for this, the only mechanisms to focus on are:

Use a timer to trigger the stimuli display/change at regular interval (in particular, look at the ExecutionModeoption of the timer, which lets you adjust how regular the timer firing is)

When the stimuli necessitating a (timed) response from the user is displayed, start a stopwatch

When the user button press is detected, read the value of the stopwatch and act in consequence.





The code for the example above:
function hf = TimedResponse
global sequence ;

    sequence = 1:10 ;
    hf = build_gui ;
   
end

function myTimerFcn(~,~,hfig)
global sequence ;
global responseTimer ;
persistent iseq ;

    hf = guidata(hfig) ;
    if isempty(iseq) ; iseq=1 ; end
    if iseq>numel(sequence) ; iseq=1 ; end
    
    hf.lbl.String = num2str(sequence(iseq)) ;
    
    if sequence(iseq) == 2
        responseTimer = tic ;
    end
    iseq = iseq+1 ;
end

function StartButtonPushed(src,~)
    hf = guidata(src) ;
    if strcmpi(hf.t.Running,'off')
        start(hf.t) ;
        hf.btnStart.String = 'Stop';
    else
        stop(hf.t) ;
        hf.btnStart.String = 'Start';
    end
end

function RespButtonPushed(src,~)
global responseTimer ;

    hf = guidata(src) ;
    ElapsedTime = toc(responseTimer) ;
    if ElapsedTime < 1
        hf.lblresp.ForegroundColor = 'g' ;
        hf.lblresp.String = sprintf('*** PASS *** (Time to respond to stimuli: %f seconds)',ElapsedTime) ;
    else
        hf.lblresp.ForegroundColor = 'r' ;
        hf.lblresp.String = sprintf('*** TOO LATE *** (Time to respond to stimuli: %f seconds)',ElapsedTime) ;
    end
    
end

function h = build_gui

    h.fig = figure('unit','normalized','CloseRequestFcn',@my_closereq);
    h.t = timer('Period',0.5,'ExecutionMode','fixedDelay') ;
    h.t.TimerFcn = @(e,v)myTimerFcn(e,v,h.fig) ;
  
    h.btnStart = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Start','unit','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.8 0.8 0.1],'Callback',@StartButtonPushed);
    h.lbl = uicontrol('Style','text','String','0','unit','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.4 0.8 0.3],'FontSize',36);
    h.btnResp = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Stimuli observed','unit','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.2 0.8 0.1],'Callback',@RespButtonPushed);
    h.lblresp = uicontrol('Style','text','String','','unit','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.05],'FontSize',12);

    h.seq = 1:10 ;
    guidata(h.fig,h)
end

function my_closereq(src,~)
    hf = guidata(src) ;
    disp('Deleting timer') ;
    if strcmpi(hf.t.Running,'on')
        stop(hf.t) ;
    end
    delete(hf.t) ;
    delete(hf.fig) ;
end

